# Update values of a Static structure

Tags: c++, struct, static

I have a structure defined for which i am making a static object.

```
struct A_struct{
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
};

static A_struct A_instance;
A_struct::A_instance.a = 12;  //This throws an error.

class ABC
{
    public:
    ABC()
    {
        cout << "ABC constructor created";
         cout << A_instance.a;

    }

};

int main()
{
    ABC aa;
}
```

I receive an error as:
.\main.cpp:7:11: error: 'A_instance' in 'struct A_struct' does not name a type
A_struct::A_instance.a = 12;

Comment: If you want to *initialize* the structure you do it as any other structure initialization (i.e. `static A_struct A_instance = { ... };`). Assignments and general statements are not allowed outside of functions.

Comment: You can't make assignments at file scope. A shorter example: `int x; x = 0; int main() {}`.

Comment: Initialization and declaration must happen in the same line at file scope, i.e., `static A_struct A_instance = {12};`.

Comment: Besides that, the syntax for the member access of the assignment is wrong. And as the problem is assignment outside of a function, you would have the same problem even if `A_instance` wasn't `static`. It being `static` is a *red herring*.

Comment: @AritraSurRoy, Issue is i have 5 elements in the structure and i want to initialise only few of those.. any help how can i do that..

Eg: i want to initialise only int b of the structure

Comment: If your compiler is new enough to support the C++20 [designated initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers) you could use that.

Comment: @Virenmahajan use designated initializers. Your code will be `static A_struct A_instance = { .b = 12 };`. Although this will work with new compilers as pointed out by @someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize fields of static structure this way

```
static A_struct A_instance {
    .a = 12, .b = 13, .c = 14
};
```